# How to stop program if there is a warning

Tags: python

I try to use nltk to do some words processing, but there is a warning. I find out the if there is the word like "***Nations�***", the program would throw a warning. I wonder if there is any way to stop the program after the warning caused. Thank you

warning:

```
*UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  if word[0].lower() not in stopwords.words():*
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A warning is a non-fatal error. Something is wrong, but the program can continue.

They can be handled with the standard library module [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) or through the command line, passing the flag `-Werror`. Programatically:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('error')
    function_raising_warning()
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
python -Werror ...
```

<sub>(does appear in accepted answer but is slightly hidden there)</sub>